# Windows 10 shortcut for application

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to assign a shortcut to activate a particular application?  For example, I have opened Outlook and minimized it.  I see an email notification.  Now I want to have a keyboard shortcut to activate Outlook and bring it to the front.

Answer (score 0):

A third-party console tool named [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) can do it. With NirCmd, to activate the Office Outlook window, all you need to do is create a shortcut with the following target:

```
nircmd win activate ititle "outlook"
```

Or the following, which uses the class name:

```
nircmd.exe win activate class rctrl_renwnd32
```

.. where `rctrl_renwnd32` is the Window class name for Microsoft Office Outlook.

And assign a keyboard hotkey for the shortcut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

*Ref: [NirCmd Command Reference](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net).*

If you need a single key shortcut, you may try a AutoHotKey solution like [this one](https://gist.github.com/adamsmith/3485120). Built-in solution such as WSH (scripting) also provide a way to activate a certain program window, but it's not much reliable.